# Javascript: How can I make an Event that Triggers only at a Specific Date and Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to set an end date like : `var end_date = new Date("December 17, 2015 21:00:00");` and have it such that when the `end_date` is reached an event is triggered.

How would I be able to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in ur script and it will works great
(don't forget to change the value of the variable end_date)

```js
function CheckEndDate() {

    var now = new Date().toString();  // current date
    var end_date = new Date("December 17, 2015 16:15:10").toString();

    if (now === end_date) {
        alert('the final date is reached !');
        return;
    }

    // call this function again in 10ms
    setTimeout(CheckEndDate, 10);
}

CheckEndDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval` and check to see if the current date is later than the target date:

```
var end_date = new Date("December 17, 2015 21:00:00");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (now > end_date) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("It's time!");   
    }           
}, 1000);
```